# Change SeriesPaint for BarChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to change the color of the bars in this BarChart, but it doesn´t work. What am i doing wrong ?
Edit: Infact, it changes only the color of the first bar in the chart, as if there were more than one series. But, the method createDataset doesn´t use addSeries, it uses only addValue, so there should be only one Series to paint. Or not?

EDIT2(SOLVED): Ok, nevermind. The error was that i created the dataset using addValue. I changed it to setValue and it works.

```
  public static JFreeChart createChart(Gruppen gruppe){

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = createDataset(gruppe);
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Altersverteilung",
            "Alter",
            "Anzahl",
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
            false, 
            true, 
            false);

    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot)chart.getPlot();
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);         
    GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.blue, 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0, 0, 64));
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);


    return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See EDIT2 in the original question above.